# Extracting most common nouns and verbs from category using numpy and NLTK

Tags: numpy, nlp, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I have a spreadsheet with reviews that I'm trying to extract two pieces of information from.

1. The most commonly used nouns and verbs used throughout all Reviews and GenMgrCom grouped by trip type including the number of times it's used (also year and DOW but I'm sure I can adapt the code for those)
2. The most commonly used nouns and verbs used throughout all Reviews and GenMgrCom grouped by sentiment of said review. (I'm not even sure where to start with this one so would appreciate even suggesting search terms that would likely yield results)

I've concatenated the reviews and GenMgrCom columns into text column, however, I'm having issues with the next step.

[image]

I'm trying to adapt the following code:

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    '''a function for removing punctuation'''
    import string
    # replacing the punctuations with no space, 
    # which in effect deletes the punctuation marks 
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    # return the text stripped of punctuation marks
    return text.translate(translator)

ByTripType = text_reviews.groupby("Trip Type")

# word frequency by trip type
wordFreqByTripType = nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist()

# for each trip type...
for name, group in ByTripType:
    sentences = group['text'].str.cat(sep = ' ')

    # convert everything to lower case (so "The" and "the" get counted as 
    # the same word rather than two different words)
    sentences = sentences.lower()

    # split the text into individual tokens    
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentences)

    # calculate the frequency of each token
    frequency = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

    # add the frequencies for each trip type to our dictionary
    wordFreqByTripType[name] = (frequency)

# now we have an dictionary where each entry is the frequency distrobution
# of words for a specific trip type. 
wordFreqByTripType.values()
```

Output:

> dict_values([FreqDist({'the': 1538, '.': 1526, 'and': 1102, 'to': 828, ',': 812, 'was': 779, 'a': 652, '...': 641, 'i': 544, 'in': 408, ...}), FreqDist     ({'.': 2465, 'the': 2391, 'and': 1657, 'to': 1400, ',': 1167, 'was': 1161, 'a': 1018, 'we': 844, 'in': 600, 'very': 580, ...}), FreqDist({'.': 1413, 'the': 1383, 'and': 974, 'to': 800, 'was': 735, ',': 604, 'a': 565, 'very': 366, 'we': 352, 'for': 347, ...}), FreqDist({'the': 318, '.': 271, 'and': 226, '?': 199, 'to': 187, 'was': 184, ',': 153, 'a': 136, 'we': 106, 'i': 86, ...}), FreqDist({'.': 823, 'the': 759, 'and': 543, 'was': 493, 'to': 435, 'i': 390, ',': 371, 'a': 322, 'in': 206, 'room': 187, ...})])

However it isn't grouped into trip type as well as i'm not sure how to add in a filter for only nouns and verbs. Every time I try to implement pos_tag I get an error expecting string because it is currently an object. It also doesn't remove punctuation however if I can extract just nouns and verbs that will solve that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this is what I ended up with which served my purpose. Thanks for your help

```
ByTripType = text_reviews.groupby("Trip Type")

def findtags(tag_prefix, tagged_text):
    cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((tag, word) for (word, tag) in tagged_text if tag.startswith(tag_prefix))
    return dict((tag, cfd[tag].most_common(10)) for tag in cfd.conditions())

for name, group in ByTripType:
    sentences = group['text'].str.cat(sep = ' ')
    sentences = sentences.lower()
    remove_punctuation(sentences)
    sentences = '"' + sentences + '"'
    text = word_tokenize(sentences)
    sentences = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    for i in ('NN', 'VBP'):
        tagdict = findtags(i, sentences)
        print(name, tagdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nltk's `pos_tag` method expects an iterable of strings, so you'll need to pos tag, filter out words that aren't nouns or verbs, then pass the list to your frequency distribution. So, something like this.

```
tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentences)
tagged_tokens = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
nouns_and_verbs = [token[0] for token in tagged_tokens if token[1] in ['VBD', 'VBP', 'NN']]
frequency = nltk.FreqDist(nouns_and_verbs)
```

Then you can return the top n for each group that you need.